Multirow cell obfuscated by \hline
Here is an unfinished (yet properly compiling) table that I made in LaTeX. I'd like to be able to say that I tried different things to fix it, but I'm not even sure where to start, as I'm coming back to LaTeX after some time. The issue is that the \hlines are crossing over the sideways merged cell, hiding the text behind it.
\usepackage{siunitx,multirow,graphicx}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
 \hline
 & \textbf{Interval} & t(\SI{}{\micro\second}) & \( \text{v}\text{c} \) (volts) 
 & \( \text{v}_\text{R} \) (volts) & real t(\SI{}{\micro\second}) & adds up to\\
 \hline
 \multirow{8}{*}{\parbox[t]{2mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Interval (+ve half period)}}} & 1 & 0 & -0.99552 & 1.0254\\
 \hline
 & 2 & 125 & 0.44408 & 0.54188\\
 \hline
 & 3 & 250 & 0.83936 & 0.16112\\
 \hline
 & 4 & 375 & 0.96136 & 0.029336\\
 \hline
 & 5 & 500 & 0.98576 & 0.02432\\
 \hline
 & 6 & 625 & 1.0004 & -0.009728\\
 \hline
 & 7 & 750 & 0.99552 & 0.004864\\
 \hline
 & 8 & 875 & 1.0053 & -0.009728\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}



\cline{2-6} ...

But consider using booktabs if you want professional-looking tables.

@cfr Thank you so much.

Off-topic: You could simplify \multirow{8}{*}{\parbox[t]{2mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Interval (+ve half period)}}} to \multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Interval (+ve half period)}}. Similarly, you could replace \SI{}{\micro\second} with \unit{\micro\second}.

Like this?

For above table I use tblr of tabularray package and recent syntax of siunitx package. For rotating of text in the first column I use rotating and makecell package:
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = { cc  
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=3.0}]
                            *{4}{Q[c, si={table-format=-1.6}]}},
                 cell{2}{1} = {r=8}{cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{ Interval (+ve half period)}\rotcell},
                 row{1}  = {guard}
                 }                                  
    & \textbf{Interval} 
            & t (\unit{\micro\second}) 
                    &   $v_c$ (volts) 
                                &   $v_R$ (volts)
                                            &   real $t$ \unit{\micro\second}   
                                                &   adds up to  \\
Interval (+ve half period)
    & 1     & 0     & -0.99552  & 1.0254    &   &               \\
    & 2     & 125   & 0.44408   & 0.54188   &   &               \\
    & 3     & 250   & 0.83936   & 0.16112   &   &               \\
    & 4     & 375   & 0.96136   & 0.029336  &   &               \\
    & 5     & 500   & 0.98576   & 0.02432   &   &               \\
    & 6     & 625   & 1.0004    & -0.009728 &   &               \\
    & 7     & 750   & 0.99552   & 0.004864  &   &               \\
    & 8     & 875   & 1.0053    & -0.009728 &   &               \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}

It is not entirely clear what you like to have in rotate cell and column headers. Anyway, be aware, that for variables are usually used italic shape.

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccS[table-format=-1.3]S[table-format=-1.6]ccc}[hvlines]i
    & \textbf{Interval} 
            & t (\unit{\micro\second}) 
                    &   {$v_c$ (volts)} 
                                &   {$v_R$ (volts)}
                                            &   real $t$ \unit{\micro\second}   
                                                &   adds up to  \\
\Block{8-1}{\rotate Interval (+ve half period)}
    & 1     & 0     & -0.995  &   1.0254    &   &               \\
    & 2     & 125   &  0.444   &  0.54188   &   &               \\
    & 3     & 250   &  0.839   &  0.16112   &   &               \\
    & 4     & 375   &  0.961   &  0.029336  &   &               \\
    & 5     & 500   &  0.985   &  0.02432   &   &               \\
    & 6     & 625   &  1.000   & -0.009728 &   &               \\
    & 7     & 750   &  0.995   &  0.004864  &   &               \\
    & 8     & 875   &  1.005   & -0.009728 &   &               \\
\end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}


